# Imrpove code for loading components

Tags: c#, unity3d

It is a usual pattern when creating a new component, to load references to other components of the same GameObject. Here is an extreme case:

```cs
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Stats))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Hunger))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Thirst))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(Navigator))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(LocationDevice))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(AttacksManager))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(ShieldEffect))]
    public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Animator animator;
        SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
        Stats stats;
        Hunger hunger;
        Thirst thirst;
        Navigator navigator;
        LocationDevice locationDevice;
        AttacksManager attacksManager;
        ShieldEffect shieldEffect;


        void Awake()
        {
            animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
            spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            stats = GetComponent<Stats>();
            hunger = GetComponent<Hunger>();
            thirst = GetComponent<Thirst>();
            navigator = GetComponent<Navigator>();
            locationDevice = GetComponent<LocationDevice>();
            attacksManager = GetComponent<AttacksManager>();
            shieldEffect = GetComponent<ShieldEffect>();
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to write this better?

Comment: Greetings, we don't review stub code on CodeReview, but actual code. Please place some actual code in your question. Otherwise this question will be put on hold pretty quickly.

Comment: @konijn Ok, corrected

Comment: Thanks! Also, sorry! I was not clear enough, this would not compile and still does not fit the guidelines, can you put the entire `EnemyController ` class ?

Comment: Now it does compile. Notice that I am not really asking a review on the code itself, but on a pattern that repeats itself a lot in my daily routine

Comment: Got ya, thanks! It's a CodeReview community thing, I am looking forward to the review of this.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Thank you!